# Add new paper size using C#

Tags: c#, printing

I want to add 3 paper sizes to windows, using C#:

```
PaperSize A11 = new PaperSize("A1+1", 594, 1051);
PaperSize A12 = new PaperSize("A1+2", 594, 1261);
PaperSize A13 = new PaperSize("A1+3", 594, 1471);
```

I try to implant this code to my project:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12229/Adding-Custom-Paper-Sizes-to-Named-Printers-2

But I'm stuck with "run as Administrator" because I'm programming for Revit API.

What is the best way to create paper size in an external program, using C#?

Comment: "stuck with run as Administrator": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator